# How to use PayPal Express Payments (PHP)

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the PayPal PHP SDK found here: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK

And I am somewhat puzzled in terms of how to complete the process.

On the outset this seems quite simple:

1. Setup your credentials
2. Create the Order
3. Check the result, and re-direct to approval link
4. User makes a payment and is sent to the SUCCESS link that you would have set.

i.e. http://example.com/pay/complete/paypal?token=8UK32254ES097084V&PayerID=SEQNPLB2JR9LY

And this is where things get a bit shakey.

Conveniently, a token and a PayerID is returned.

And according to the documentation, you now need to "Capturing the Order" and the following code is provided:

```
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCaptureRequest;
// Here, OrdersCaptureRequest() creates a POST request to /v2/checkout/orders
// $response->result->id gives the orderId of the order created above
$request = new OrdersCaptureRequest("APPROVED-ORDER-ID");
$request->prefer('return=representation');
try {
    // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
    $response = $client->execute($request);
    
    // If call returns body in response, you can get the deserialized version from the result attribute of the response
    print_r($response);
}catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex->statusCode;
    print_r($ex->getMessage());
}
```

What is confusing is that the OrdersCaptureRequest requires an "APPROVED-ORDER-ID"

But all that has been returned is a "token" and a "PayerID".

So my question is, what is this APPROVED-ORDER-ID, and where do I get it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> what is this APPROVED-ORDER-ID, and where do I get it

At that moment, sourced from `token=` . It should correspond to an Order Id you received in the response to your step 2 ("Create the Order")

---

For step 3, it is better to use no redirects whatsoever. Instead, implement this front-end UI, which offers a far superior in-context experience that keeps your site loaded in the background: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

There is no reason for a modern website to be redirecting unnecessarily

Comment: OK - so I could store the token and order id in a table then call from there. Ideally, though, I would prefer PayPal to call an IPN and set the status asynchronously. I note an IPN can be set although I am struggling to find the corresponding developer resources that clearly explain how to set this up.

Comment: Here's the server-side guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ -- you want two routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction', and one for 'Capture Transaction'.  Call these routes from the JS UI linked in the answer.